# indexSetWithIndexesInRange is not doing what expected

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsindexset, nsrange

I want to select some objects from an array. Therefore I'm using begin and end indexes of my selection.

```
NSLog(@"start:%d\nend:%d", startIndex, endIndex);
NSIndexSet *myIndexes = [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:NSMakeRange(startIndex, endIndex)];
NSLog(@"%d", [myIndexes lastIndex]);
```

The first NSLog gives me

> startIndex:49
>   endIndex:67

The second NSLog gives me

> 115

Why do I have 115 as highest number? It should be 67. Of course the app crashes:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[NSArray objectsAtIndexes:]: index 115 beyond bounds [0 .. 96]'

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`NSRange`'s members are `location` and `length`, not `start` and `end`. This means you need to create your `NSRange` struct like this:

```
NSMakeRange(startIndex, endIndex - startIndex);
```

Comment: This saved me lots of time and energy!